# How to install multiple vendors into one project using composer

Tags: paypal, composer-php, stripe-payments

I would like to know how to install multiple vendors into one project using composer. E.g I would like to install Paypal SDK and Stripe SDK into my project.

How do I go about this, and how would the folder structure look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install as many dependencies as you wish using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). For instance, to install both [Paypal's](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation-Composer) and [Stripe's](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#composer) PHP libraries, you'd run these commands:

```
composer require "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php:*"
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

Afterwards, both libraries would be installed in the `vendor` directory, and both would be automatically included in your code when you load dependencies with:

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
```